# Getting the sum of variables and numbers from columns using gridlayout

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is my very first post here and i am very new to programming, ive started a project in android studio but i've become stuck on a couple of things because my lack of knowledge.

I have three different tabs and i want to make the calculation on the second one.

So my question is how do i calculate data in columns inside of the gridlayout?

My component tree looks like this in tab2:

RelativeLayout>Scrollview>Gridlayout.

I have inserted several textedits on column 2 and 3 and my goal is to make calculations based on their input and then insert them as results at the bottom of the tab.

2nd column includes numbers only and the 3rd column includes variables.

I want to make the variables the user enters on the 3rd column equal to numbers, for example A=20 B=17.5 etc

So when its calculating its automatically changing the variable to the 
equal number.

How do i proceed?

**Tab2 java class:**

```
package com.example.minmerit;

/**
 * Created by lukin on 2017-06-14.
 */

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class Tab2Betyg extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2betyg, container, false);
        return rootView;

    }
}
```

**Tab2 layout xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="450dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.minmerit.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/textview">


        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/POÄNG"
                android:layout_width="67dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:fontFamily="monospace"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:text="100"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First, give your EditTexts some proper IDs, like

```
<EditText             
 android:id="@+id/number_1"
...
```

Then in eg. [onViewCreated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated(android.view.View,%20android.os.Bundle)) make changeListeners:

```
EditText number_1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number_1);
number_1.addTextChangedListener( changeListener );
// change listeners for other fields

TextWatcher changeListener  = new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(s);
        // do something with "a"
   }
  });
```

Comment: First of all it cant resolve methods findViewById and changeListeners

How do i get the sum of the colum 2 and 3 in the gridlayout?

Comment: GridLayout is only for visual arrangement of inner views. To sum "column" (or to be exact: sum values of EditTexts from columns) you have to give them IDs. Whats more, yout GridLayout is missing some attributes, like columnCount. Look here, maybe this will help: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_the_Android_GridLayout_in_XML_Layout_Resources
Please look also at this TableLayout, maybe this will be better for you: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/grid.html

Comment: Okay that explains alot haha, ive finally managed to configure gridlayout so im not really that happy to try changing it now. 

Why do i need columncount? I have inserted layoutrow/layoutcolumn if thats what you mean. 

Ive been looking around for some time and (tell me if im wrong) the easiest way to be able to do what i want is to create a SQLiteDatabase. 

Ive set proper ids to the edittexts depending on what column they are in. 

Thanks!

Comment: If you have proper layout with GridLayout, then it's fine - there is always many ways to do what you need.
You have to use SQLiteDatabase if you want to save your data permanently (not lose it after app close). But then you should also check how to fill GridLayout programatically (because you won't know how many rows you will have in your database). Is that what you need?

Comment: What do you mean by filling GridLayout programatically?  I need as many rows in the database as in the gridlayout, depending on the amount of edittexts. 

Sorry, im really new to all of this hehe

Comment: I don't know what your app have to do, so I'm only guessing.
1) If you want to store data permanently, then yes, you have to use SQLiteDatabase. Or just save data in txt file in JSON (maybe this is not too profesional, but it's easier than database).
2) If you have fixed data amount, then GridLayout created in XML is enough. But probably you will want to add and delete rows, then you have to add and delete rows in GridLayout programatically.
But both of those functions are something else than what you've asked. Start small, with fixed data amount and not saving it, then add other functions.

Comment: LukasVonRosen, did you manage to calculate sum of EditTexts? Was my answers helpful?